# Java Pattern does not return leftmost match

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse the output of a program to search for errors. The errors are indicated as:

> [(FieldName/Value) = (**phrase**/**What is Up John Carl?**) failed rule **alphanumeric**]  [(FieldName/Value) = (**newLabel**/**Óscar's IPad**) failed rule **illegalchars**]

There can be more than one error per line, and for each error I want to retrieve the words/sentences in bold. In order to do that I'm creating a regular expression as follows:

```
static String s1 = Pattern.quote("[(FieldName/Value) = (");
static String s2 = Pattern.quote(") failed rule");
static String s3 = Pattern.quote("]");
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s1 + "(\\w+)/(.+)" + s2 + "(.+)" + s3);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String token = matcher.group(1);
    sb.append("#");
    sb.append(token);
    token = matcher.group(2);
    sb.append("#");
    sb.append(token);
    token = matcher.group(3).trim();
    sb.append("#");
    sb.append(token);
}
```

But the output is :

```
#phrase#What is Up John Carl?) failed rule alphanumeric] [(FieldName/Value) = (newLabel/Óscar's IPad#illegalchars
```

So it is not returning two matches, just one. It is matching the second group to the rest of the string, instead of stopping at the first `"failed rule"`. I suppose it is due to the first `(.+)` in the pattern, but the thing is that anything can go in there, so I need the `(.+)`. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read at the end of [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) `(.+)` is **Greedy**, so it will search for max substring that fits regex, for example in `"(ab)(cd)"` regex `(.+)` will return `ab)(cd`.

What you want is **Reluctant quantifier** `(.+?)` (there is `?` mark after `+`). Thanks to that regex will try to find minimal substring that matches your regex

`"(ab)(cd)"` with `(.+?)` will find `ab` and `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s1+"(\\w+)/(.*?)" + s2 + "(.*?)" + s3);
```

Comment: You should also take a moment to describe why this works, rather than just posting code only.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the quantifiers non-greedy.  You do this with the "?" symbol.

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s1 + "(\\w+)/(.*?)" + s2 + "(.*?)" + s3);
```

Take a look at this other example in SO:

[Non-greedy Regular Expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931183/non-greedy-regular-expression-in-java)