# PHP to remove xml

Tags: php, regex, xml

I need some help with a problem if possible.

```
<IndexFile index="dlc:blahblahblahblah.zip" version="1.19.0" />
```

How would I use php to remove everything in the above line of code except

blahblahblahblah.zip

Note: blahblah isn't actual name, the name changes; I just need to remove the xml on either side of the .zip file.

I've tried a few things like strip_tags() but nothing works up to now.

Comment: can you provide actual xml that you want to remove. This information is insufficient for providing answer

Comment: By using `preg_quote` on your `$find` variable you ruin any regex in it and every character will be considered that exact character (including `(.+?)`)

Comment: @unknown1 You can still use `preg_quote`, just don't use it on stuff you want to regex. `$pattern = '/^.*' . preg_quote('index="dlc:', '/') . '(.+?).*$/m'`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test string was 
`<IndexFile index="dlc:blahblahblahblah.zip" version="4.19.0" />`

Your regex pattern should be :   `index="dlc:(.+?)"`.

Your answer is:
`blahblahblahblah.zip`

Try it out at https://regex101.com/

See this answer for greedy vs nongreedy matching: [java-pattern-does-not-return-leftmost-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851029/java-pattern-does-not-return-leftmost-match)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you have to use an XML parser to parse the file and use XPaths/looping to get that item.

If that is the only line, why can't you just use a Regex to extract the value? `index="[a-zA-Z0-9_.-:]*"` (or `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-:]*.zip`)?

Again, you need to think about the future impacts.